# How do I inject a WebRequest/Response dependency?

Tags: c#, tdd, dependency-injection, mocking

I'm struggling to separate the dependencies in the following code:

```
    public static SiteConnector ConnectToSite(String Logon, String Password)
    {

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_URI);
        ConfigureRequest(Logon, Password, webRequest);
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Cookie ReposonseCookie;
        //this looks for a cookie and spitsout a value based on response
        int value = ProcessResponse(webResponse,out  ReposonseCookie);

        return new SiteConnector(ReposonseCookie, value);

    }
```

Essentially I want to unit test without relying on the request to the external website.

What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how that class looks off of the top of my head, but you can always wrap them around your own, testable class.

```
public class WebRequestWrapper
{
   internal WebRequestWrapper() {..}

   public WebRequestWrapper(WebRequest req)
   {
      _innerRequest = req;
   }


   public virtual string Url
   {
      return _innerReq.Url;
   }

   //repeat, make all necessary members virtual
}
```

then you can use RhinoMocks to create a PartialMock of this class.  IT will override any of the virtual properties.

Comment: Very old question but I had a case today for this. WebRequest is an abstract class, so it cannot be resolved through dependency injection. The WebRequestWrapper class still apply to solve this, but the WebRequestWrapper constructor is not needed.